# Run a shell script having individual icon in dock

Tags: command-line, automator, icon, zsh

### Target

Run a command line tool or script displayed with a specific icon in dock. A terminal window should not be displayed. I would like to use this to start [octave](https://octave.org/) with its gui.

### What I tried

- **Automator**

  1. Create an automator application and running a shell script.
  2. Change its icon using finders file information window
  3. I now have an individual application icon

  - **Result:** After start, automator calls terminal and terminal icon appears in dock hosting my command line tool. My indiviual icon is not showing up in dock while running.
- **Shell script**

  1. Create a shell script `myapp.sh` starting my command line tool.
  2. Make executable with `chmod u+x myapp.sh`
  3. Can not change icon at all using finders information window.

  - **Result:** When clicking a terminal window is opened.

### Possible solutions

- Use a command line tool to change the icon of the currently running process?
- Start terminal with a specific icon?
- ...?

Comment: Probably more stable to just create a small application that performs the shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First locate your **octave-gui** Unix Executable file.  This is the path my version is located.

/usr/local/Cellar/octave/7.3.0_3/libexec/octave/7.3.0/exec/x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0/octave-gui

Then in **Finder**, go ahead and change its icon in the ***Get Info*** window.

Next, create a new **Script Editor.app** document and paste this following **AppleScript** code.

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/octave --gui"
```

*(I installed **Octave** using **Homebrew** in **Terminal.app**. After it was installed, to retrieve it's full path to use in the above **AppleScript** code, in Terminal, the command `which octave`... Returned its full path.)*

Next, save your new **Script Editor** document as an application.  (I saved my version as ***Launch_Octave.app***)

Now, anytime you run the ***Launch_Octave.app***, both the ***Launch_Octave.app*** and **octave-gui with its custom icon** will appear in the Dock.

However, you can hide the ***Launch_Octave.app*** from appearing in the Dock, so you can only see **octave-gui with its custom icon** appearing in the Dock by adding these two following lines to the **Info.plist** file within the **Contents** folder inside the ***Launch_Octave.app*** package. (Right click ***Launch_Octave.app*** in Finder and choose "Show Package Contents")

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

As you can see in this following animation, I am double clicking on the ***Launch_Octave.app*** located on my Desktop (which launches the **octave-gui with its custom icon**, which appears in the Dock while ***Launch_Octave.app*** does not appear in the Dock.

[image]